# Online card game + chat with PHP

Tags: php, comet, playing-cards, ape, ajax-push

What would be a good way to make a online card game with chat-function in PHP?

A colleague mentioned Ajax Push Engine ([APE](http://www.ape-project.org/)) but APE's latest release is from 2009.
[Orbited](http://orbited.org/) on the other hand doesn't seem to work with PHP.

Is there a viable alternative to those two that works with PHP?

Comment: What aspect of building the card game are you exactly inquiring about? The algorithms? How to display the cards? How to connect two players? What kind of card game is it?

Comment: @Pekka, the game's called whist. I was / am inquiring about the whole game (or as much as possible) actually.

Comment: @Pekka, primarily against other players. Computer is an extra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just give up. Making a card game with PHP is far too much hard since PHP is not really meant for this kind of things.
Anyway if you really want to give it a try, just use PHP, MYSQL (PDO for example) and AJAX (with jQuery, which i personally love).
Also most of the chats written in PHP are made up with AJAX and most of them use jQuery as well.

I've recently seen also an html5 stuff for chats: http://weevilgenius.net/2010/10/html-5-websocket-chat-demo/ . But i seriously would never go with such a new technology for a business site.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That means I'll most likely go Java or C# for the game. I'll leave this question open for a few more days, and if none post a "better" answer, yours it'll be.

Comment: @Jeff Pigarelli: Can you talk about what some of the specific technical limitations are, that make PHP a bad match for card games? (For example, data-refresh problems)